# What is the best tool for build automation for a one-man software shop?

Tags: .net, build-automation

I am building Windows apps for a few clients.  I read Joel on Software and took the Joel Test and realized I don't quite measure up.  One place I am lacking is automated builds.  What should I use to have automated builds?  I have Windows apps that use .NET 1.1, 2.0, and 3.5.  Also, I need to be able to build my .vdproj to create MSI's.  I am looking for something that is free and would work well for a one-man team.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeamCity Professional Edition from JetBrains. http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

Answer (score 10):

[CruiseControl.Net](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/) and [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) are the standard tools (and open source too), so there will be a lot of community support available. [MSBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild) is now open source, too

It will be quite a lot of work to set it all up, but it will be very powerful and have lots of room for growth too.

Comment: MSBuild is also a logical choice for .Net development, instead of nant.

Comment: Also look at [Hyper Build](http://www.ssware.com/hyperbuild/hyperbuild.htm) for this.

Answer (score 2):

MSBuild has been useful for me

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in [MSBuild engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx). If you already have a solution or project file this fits very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I make and sell a tool called Build Automator (http://www.buildautomator.com) that was written for build and automation stuff.  It is a bit designed for a database language that I use (Clarion) but it works well with MS-Build for VS or Delphi (RAD Studio)  I haven't had as much time as I'd like to update it lately, but I use it almost every single day and it saves me hours every week!  I have customers who use it in complex build operations along with other build automation tools.  Just my $0.02:)

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I've used both CruiseControl and TeamCity extensively.  For a one man shop, TeamCity is far easier to setup and configure than CruiseControl.

For your build scripts, you can't go wrong with MsBuild or NAnt.  I've also been considering Powershell for this but I have not attempted it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have been very pleased with NUBuild since it was released. Based on your requirement I think NUBuild will be a perfect match. You can set it up (only once) under 10 minutes and ready to build your projects. Check it out -

http://nubuild.codeplex.com